# Allocation of memory to guest os

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtualization, virtual-memory

I have 6gb memory on my host OS (Windows 7 64bit), I am planning to install Oracle Linux as guest using Virtual Box.

How much memory should I allocate to guest OS? In guest OS I am planning to install Oracle database and Weblogic application server.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: Feel free to discuss this question in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/118/root-access).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no rule for "how much memory you need", it depends on a million factors: How many users are connecting to the database, will the host os need to do tasks while the vm is running. Would a 5 second execution time for a query on the database be acceptable, would a 5 minute one be acceptable too?

Really you just need to test and find out what you need then just use:

## As much as you need to get the job done.

Comment: Scott, I am using this for home purpose with only one user being connected to database with not very complex queries or having a big database.

Comment: Ok, you answered 4 questions out of the 1,000,000 that need to be answered to give you an exact number. Give it enough memory to boot the OS + 100 MB, if its too slow (due to it running out of memory, be sure that memory is what is causing the slowness), bump it up till you no longer consider it too slow.

Comment: Scott, Thanks for this. Any documentation available for this, some kind of best practices?

Comment: Not really, however reading your other question about your slowdown makes me think you have a problem with a too slow of a hard drive, not memory. Take a look at the Disk tab of the [Resource Monitor](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/closer-windows-resource-monitor/) and see if you are getting high queue times on your hard drive. If so, your disk is too slow and there is not much you can do other than get another disk and run the VM on that seperate drive.

Comment: Scott, thanks for reading my other question. I would like to let you know that this is in fact a brand new laptop with more memory, the issue I had with slowness is my old laptop.